# Keyboard covers UITextView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, swift5

I have an extension which scrolls the scrollView up so it does not cover UITextField, however for UITextView it does not scroll up. The extension looks like this:

```
extension SummaryViewController {
    
    ///Register for keyboard willHide willShow notifiication
    func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(SummaryViewController.keyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let duration: TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve: UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            
            if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
                //close keyboard
                
                scrollView.contentInset = .zero
                
            } else {
                //open keyboard
                let height: CGFloat = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)!.size.height
                scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: height, right: 0)
            }
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                           delay: TimeInterval(0),
                           options: animationCurve,
                           animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I call **registerKeyboardNotifications()** in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a UITextField move up when the keyboard is present - on starting to edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-can-i-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-the-keyboard-is-present-on-starting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **UITextView** it doesn't work, so i do this with **contentOffset**.

**Swift 5**

```
extension SummaryViewController {
    
    private func registerKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIControl.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIControl.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let keyboardFrameValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
        let keyboardFrame = view.convert(keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue, from: nil)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardFrame.size.height)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = .zero
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, great))

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is setting scrollview's contentOffset.  You can set it when your user taps on the textField to edit it like below:

```
func begunEditingTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
            let point = sender(sender, to: self.contentView)
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: point.y - self.view.frame.height*0.1), animated: true)
}
```

**Note** that I'm adding a space of 10% of screen's height as padding.